# OpenXML Word Document - Unreadable content found after altchunk

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I build a small application using .NET 6 that is replacing values inside a word document and saving a copy.
Some keys are replaced with other files content using an AltChunk.

Using file A, in which I merge AltChunk1, the output is working fine.
Using file B with same AltChunk1, the output produce the error "found unreadable content" when opening with Word.
Using file B and a different AltChunk file (even the same after I trimmed it) can, in some cases, work.

I don't have any clue what the issue might be.
I tried comparing files using OpenXML productivity tool however:

- File A and File B have a lot of differences, it is really hard to find anything that would explain this behavior
- They are identical in the place the AltChunk is put.
- Tried comparing the not working result with what word is creating with a repair but word is not keeping the AltChunk, it completely merges content of AltChunk with File B making any comparison almost impossible with my non-working result.

Here is the code Is use:
First method is creating the AltChunk from file, then calls methods used to replace "keys" with the wanted value (including case where the key is split accross various runs)

```
internal static void MergeOutSideDocument(string key, string filePath, IEnumerable<string> outsideDocs)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot replace empty key.");
            if (!File.Exists(filePath) || outsideDocs.Any(path => !File.Exists(path))) throw new FileNotFoundException();

            using WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true);
            List<OpenXmlElement> altChunks = new();
            foreach (var outsideDoc in outsideDocs)
            {
                var existingIds = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<AltChunk>();
                string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(outsideDoc, FileMode.Open))
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                altChunks.Add(new AltChunk()
                {
                    Id = altChunkId
                });
                inMemoryAltChunkIds.Add(altChunkId);
            }

            var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            SetElementForKey(key, altChunks,
                body.Descendants<Paragraph>().First(par => par.Contains(key)),
                body);
        }

        private static void SetElementForKey(string key, List<OpenXmlElement> replacements, OpenXmlElement el, Body body)
        {
            List<Run> previousRuns = new();
            if (el?.InnerText.Contains(key) != true) return;

            for (int i = 0; i <= el.Descendants<Run>().Count(); i++)
            {
                var innerText = string.Join("", previousRuns.Select(r => r.InnerText));
                if (innerText.Contains(key))
                {
                    var usedRuns = GetRequiredRunsForText(previousRuns, key);
                    var firstRun = usedRuns.First();
                    MergeRunsWithKey(key, usedRuns, firstRun);
                    var usedRun = usedRuns.First();
                    var firstPart = usedRun.InnerText.IndexOf(key) != -1 ? usedRun.InnerText[..usedRun.InnerText.IndexOf(key)] : "";
                    ReplaceText(key, "", usedRun);
                    foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                        el.Parent.InsertAfter(replacement, el);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usedRun.InnerText)) usedRun.Remove();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.InnerText)) el.Remove();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    previousRuns.Add(el.Descendants<Run>().ElementAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

        private static void MergeRunsWithKey(string key, List<Run> usedRuns, Run firstRun)
        {
            while (!usedRuns.First().InnerText.Contains(key))
            {
                AddText(usedRuns.Skip(1).First().InnerText, firstRun);
                usedRuns.Skip(1).First().Remove();
                usedRuns.RemoveAt(1);
            }
        }

        private static void AddText(string newText, Run run)
        {
            Text text = run.Elements<Text>().LastOrDefault();
            if (text == null)
            {
                run.Append(new Text());
                text = run.Elements<Text>().Last();
            }
            text.Text += newText;

            if (text.Text.StartsWith(" ") || text.Text.EndsWith(" "))
                text.Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve;
        }
```

What can I do to understand where the problem lies?

I tried replacing some values I don't understand in File B with the ones from File A (header and footer have rectangles with different gfxdata values, the "recovered" from word was setting the same values as File A).
I tried a different way of generating the AltChunkIds and storing a global list for the file.
I tried comparing various parts of the documents (File A and B or Fil B's result and its recovered version). There are differences, but too many and none seem to be relevant.